# Operator splitting method on three assets black scholes equation

Tags: black-scholes, pricing, black-scholes-pde, finite-difference-method, finite-difference

Currently I am studying finite difference method on derivatives with three (or more) underlyings and little bit confused on operator splitting method because two papers have different result.

For the follwing differential equation,
$$
u_\tau(x,y,z,\tau) = rxu_x+ryu_y+rzu_z+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_x^2x^2u_{xx}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_y^2y^2u_{yy}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_z^2z^2u_{zz}+\rho_{xy}\sigma_x\sigma_yxyu_{xy}+\rho\sigma_y\sigma_zyzu_{yz}+\rho_{zx}\sigma_z\sigma_xu_{zx}-ru
$$

First paper, [Comparision of numerical schemes on multi-dimensional black-scholes equations](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/20cb/878068524813d24a13bb8da79d6100e00a3d.pdf) ended up with

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \tau}=L_xu+L_yu+L_zu
$$
where
$$
L_xu = \frac{1}{2}\sigma_x^2x^2u_{xx}+rxu_x+\frac{1}{2}\rho_{xy}\sigma_x\sigma_yxyu_{xy}+\frac{1}{2}\rho_{xz}\sigma_z\sigma_xu_{xz}-\frac{1}{3}ru \\
L_yu = \frac{1}{2}\sigma_y^2y^2u_{yy}+ryu_y+\frac{1}{2}\rho_{yx}\sigma_y\sigma_xyxu_{yx}+\frac{1}{2}\rho_{yz}\sigma_y\sigma_zu_{yz}-\frac{1}{3}ru \\
L_zu = \frac{1}{2}\sigma_z^2z^2u_{zz}+rzu_z+\frac{1}{2}\rho_{zx}\sigma_z\sigma_xzxu_{zx}+\frac{1}{2}\rho_{zy}\sigma_z\sigma_yu_{zy}-\frac{1}{3}ru
$$
(Original paper took derivative wrt $t$ and I changed to $\tau = T-t$ here)

and the second paper, [A practical finite difference method for the three-dimensional black-scholes equation](http://elie.korea.ac.kr/%7Ecfdkim/papers/Practical3DELS.pdf) defined them as
$$
L_xu = \frac{1}{2}\sigma_x^2x^2u_{xx}+rxu_x+\frac{1}{3}\rho_{xy}\sigma_x\sigma_yxyu_{xy}+\frac{1}{3}\rho_{yz}\sigma_y\sigma_zyzu_{yz}+\frac{1}{3}\rho_{xz}\sigma_x\sigma_zxzu_{xz}-\frac{1}{3}ru \\
L_yu = \frac{1}{2}\sigma_y^2y^2u_{yy}+ryu_y+\frac{1}{3}\rho_{yx}\sigma_y\sigma_xyxu_{yx}+\frac{1}{3}\rho_{yz}\sigma_y\sigma_zyzu_{yz}+\frac{1}{3}\rho_{xz}\sigma_x\sigma_zxzu_{xz}-\frac{1}{3}ru \\
L_zu = \frac{1}{2}\sigma_z^2z^2u_{zz}+rzu_z+\frac{1}{3}\rho_{xy}\sigma_x\sigma_yxyu_{xy}+\frac{1}{3}\rho_{zy}\sigma_z\sigma_yzyu_{zy}+\frac{1}{3}\rho_{zx}\sigma_z\sigma_xzxu_{zx}-\frac{1}{3}ru \\
$$

So I wonder which derivation I should use or they are just indifferent